# SVN Checkout failing?

Tags: svn, mediawiki

I'm trying to get the files from here-http://svn.wikimedia.org/svnroot/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/skins but everytime I do, it gives me Could not read status line: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Any ideas why?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try that address in your browser? The server is responding to pings, but there's seems to be something wrong with apache.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me now. I would assume they were in the middle of an apache upgrade or similar network reconfiguration.